# IBM RAD ctrl+left on method or class name opens the .class file instead of java file

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, ibm-rad

I am using IBM RAD 7. whenever i do ctrl+left click on method or class name then it will opens the .class file instead of java file.

I Don't have any idea how to resolve the problem.

Comment: Do you mean left click :) What is the class you are clicking on, is it located in a third party library?

Comment: yes it is left click. and method or class is in another project.

Comment: Can you verify that the project is included in your Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects?

Comment: If that project is include as a library, you can also attach the source code to that jar?

Comment: it is included as Project in Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects.

Comment: This is just a wild guess, but the project itself is not include twice maybe. (Once as project / once as a jar?)

Comment: I've just tested this under RAD 9.0.1 and it works perfectly. i.e. I declare an instance of ClassX in project Y, (Where Project X is on the Java Build Path->Projects) Ctrl-Left Click on ClassX, and up comes the source from Project X. What Version of RAD are you using, and on what OS?